# Painting child of a custom RenderProxyBox multiple times during single paint phase

Tags: flutter, flutter-engine

I'm building a custom `RenderObject` to draw multiple portions of child widget in different positions and clipped differently (layout, hit testing, semantics and other RenderObject aspects are not revelant here). I managed to get it working, but code breaks for more complex descendants (eg. `FlutterLogo()` works but `Scaffold()` not) - child is painted only on the first (or maybe last) `paintChild` call.

I've read `RenderObject` documentation and haven't found anything that would prohibit painting the child multiple times during single paint phase. On the other hand, I haven't found any RenderObjects that would do this. I suspect that this won't work when child is creating its own layer and the layer gets reused between `paint` calls. Wrapping any `child` in `RepaintBoundary` seems enough to break it.

```dart
class RenderExample extends RenderProxyBox {

  final _clipLayerHandles = [for (int i = 0; i < _gameChildCount; i++) LayerHandle<ClipRectLayer>()];

  //...

  @override
  bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final handle in _clipLayerHandles) {
      handle.layer?.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    for (...) {
      _clipLayerHandles[childIndex].layer = context.pushClipRect(
        needsCompositing,
        offset,
        parentRect,
        (context, offset) => context.paintChild(child!, offset + parentOffset - childOffset),
        oldLayer: _clipLayerHandles[childIndex].layer,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any insights? Is it something that is impossible in the engine? If so, why? Is there any hack to make it work?

Comment: cannot you use one `pushClipPath` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I want to draw portions of the child in arbitrary positions, eg. top-left quadrant of child in center of parent, and bottom-right quadrant of child in top-right quadrant of parent. I know this seems like an odd use-case but I'm just researching what's possible ;)

Comment: since your `isRepaintBoundary` is `true` you can always use `OffsetLayer.toImage` and then draw that raster image any times you want

Comment: Isn't Scene.toImage to slow to call on every repaint?

Comment: and your child render box changes every single frame?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming my child render object can really be anything.

Comment: i mean if it changes / morphs / animates every single frame - your child render box can still be anything but if it is mostly static you dont have to call `toImage` on every repaint

Comment: That won't work if child itself animates every single frame. Basically, I just want to know if there's a way to paint child multiple times during single paint phase, assuming I don't want to rasterize it with toImage as you suggested (still, it's a good idea)