Drawing the same child multiple times in the same `RenderObject`
I have a RenderObject which needs to apply different ColorFilters to different clipped parts (or Paths) of the child. As far as I understand, I need to be able to draw the child multiple times. Is this possible, or is there another way to selectively apply ColorFilters only to parts of a child?
This is what I've tried:
context.pushColorFilter(
      offset,
      _grayscale(1),
      (context, offset) => context.pushClipPath(
        true,
        offset,
        context.estimatedBounds,
        Path()
          ..addRect(
            Rect.fromCenter(
              center: context.estimatedBounds.center - offset,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            ),
          )
          ..addRect(
            Rect.fromCenter(
              center: context.estimatedBounds.center - offset / 2,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            ),
          ),
        (context, offset) => context.paintChild(child!, offset),
      ),
    );

This works to do it once (apply a ColorFilter to one Path, and avoid painting the rest), but using it again 'covers'/'removes'/etc. the previous result.

Paint the same widget instance multiple times in a single frame, is not allowed in Flutter. Each widget can only be associated with one RenderObject at a time.
Need to create distinct instances of the child widget for each draw.

@DroidFlutter Can you quote where this is specified? I suspect that this could be the case, but I don't see anything that explicitly says it isn't. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713873/painting-child-of-a-custom-renderproxybox-multiple-times-during-single-paint-pha for an old similar question that was never answered satisfactorily.  If it isn't possible, is there no other way? For example, applying a color filter to a path over everything else?

You can find here with Manipulating the RenderObject https://www.dhiwise.com/post/understanding-flutter-renderobject-class-the-core-of-flutter

This doesn't say I can't paint the same child multiple times. One widget still only belongs to one RenderObject: it is just painted multiple times.
